# Request Web Page in c# spoofing the Host

Tags: c#, http, http-headers

I need to create a request for a web page delivered to our web sites, but I need to be able to set the host header information too.  I have tried this using HttpWebRequest, but the Header information is read only (Or at least the Host part of it is).  I need to do this because we want to perform the initial request for a page before the user can.  We have 10 web server which are load balanced, so we need to request the file from each of the web servers.

I have tried the following:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.5/filename.htm");
request.Headers.Set("Host", "www.mywebsite.com");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Obviously this does not work, as I can't update the header, and I don't know if this is indeed the right way to do it.

Comment: This question is very closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323264/http-request-bypass-dns-net Maybe someone should close it as duplicate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have managed to find out a more long winded route by using sockets.  I found the answer in the MSDN page for IPEndPoint:

```
string getString = "GET /path/mypage.htm HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.mysite.mobi\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n";
Encoding ASCII = Encoding.ASCII;
Byte[] byteGetString = ASCII.GetBytes(getString);
Byte[] receiveByte = new Byte[256];
Socket socket = null;
String strPage = null;
try
{
    IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.23.1.93"), 80);
    socket = new Socket(ip.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    socket.Connect(ip);
}
catch (SocketException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Source:" + ex.Source);
    Console.WriteLine("Message:" + ex.Message);
}
socket.Send(byteGetString, byteGetString.Length, 0);
Int32 bytes = socket.Receive(receiveByte, receiveByte.Length, 0);
strPage = strPage + ASCII.GetString(receiveByte, 0, bytes);

while (bytes > 0)
{
    bytes = socket.Receive(receiveByte, receiveByte.Length, 0);
    strPage = strPage + ASCII.GetString(receiveByte, 0, bytes);
}
socket.Close();
```

Answer (score 11):

Although this is a very late answer, maybe someone can get benefit of it

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://192.168.1.1"));
request.Headers.GetType().InvokeMember("ChangeInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, request.Headers, new object[] {"Host","www.mysite.com"});
```

Reflection is your friend :)

Comment: L.B - this is cool, I am new to C# and don't know what's reflection and how did your answer worked for me

Comment: Note: This will change the host, but it will be overwritten with the value in the url that you send the request to.

Answer (score 4):

I had a problem where the URL dns I used had several different IP addresses, I wanted to call each address separately using the same dns name in the host - the solution is using a proxy:

```
string retVal = "";
            // Can't change the 'Host' header property because .NET protects it
            // HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            // request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.Host, DEPLOYER_HOST);
            // so we must use a workaround
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Proxy = new WebProxy(ip);
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        retVal += line;
                }
            }
            return retVal;
```

Host header is set from 'url' automatically by .NET, and 'ip' contains the actual address of the web server you want to contact (you can use a dns name here too)

Comment: Obviously this won't work when we actually need to use a proxy :)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I came across this same exact problem, and I found a better solution to this then using sockets or reflection...

What I did was create a new class that durives from WebHeaderCollection and bypasses validation of what you stick inside it:

```
public class MyHeaderCollection:WebHeaderCollection
{
    public new void Set(string name, string value)
    {
        AddWithoutValidate(name, value);
    }
    //or
    public new string this[string name]
    {
        get { return base[name]; }
        set { AddWithoutValidate(name, value); }
    }
}
```

and here is how you use it:

```
    var http = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/");
    var headers = new MyHeaderCollection();
    http.Headers = headers;

    //Now you can add/override anything you like without validation:
    headers.Set("Host", http.RequestUri.Host);
    //or
    headers["Host"] = http.RequestUri.Host;
```

Hope this helps anyone looking for this!

Comment: This doesn't work in 3.5SP1- the collection passed to Headers is not preserved, it gets copied into a new WebHeaderCollection, so all the headers get revalidated.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but these days, you can do.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.5/filename.htm");
request.Host = "www.mywebstite.com";
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, little bit of research turns up this:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=384456

Seems MS *may* do something about this at some point.

Comment: I get the exception "ArgumentException : The 'Host' header cannot be modified directly. Parameter name: name". I presume that it is read only in the HttpWebRequest class

Comment: Wouldn't it have been better to create a new answer rather than undelete and completely rewrite your old one?

Comment: eh, possibly - not clear on the etiquette here (pointers anyone?), but I fell on the side of preserving history rather than starting again. I do wonder if I should have preserved the failed answer to visibly display it doesn't work.

Comment: The trouble is that the comments and votes that are still connected to this answer no longer make any sense. As such, in my oppinion, a new answer would have been better.

Answer (score 0):

The "Host" header is protected and cannot be modified programmatically. I suppose to work around this, you could try and bind via reflection to the private "InnerCollection" property of the WebRequest object and calling the "Set" ar "Add" method on it to modify the Host header. I haven't tried this, but from a quick look at the source code in Reflector, I think it's easily accomplished. But yeah, binding to private properties of framework objects is not the best way to accomplish things. :) Use only if you MUST.

edit: Or like the other guy mentions in the linked question, just open up a socket and do a quick "GET" manually. Should be a no brainer, if you don't need to tinker with other stuff, like cookies or whatever else niceties the HttpWebRequest provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my solution for this problem, it posted here :

[How to set custom "Host" header in HttpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450937/how-to-set-custom-host-header-in-httpwebrequest/18572236#18572236)

This can help you to edit host header, and avoid to using proxy and direct socket requests.

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing. 
For those still on .NET 2.0 
It is in fact quite easy, if you know how.

Problem is, you can't set the host header, because the framework won't let you change the value at runtime. (.net framework 4.0+ will let you override host in a httpwebrequest).

Next attempt will be setting the header with reflection - as demonstrated in the top upvoted answer here - to get around it, which will let you change the header value. But at runtime, it will **overwrite** this value with the host part **of the url**, which means reflection will bring you nothing, which is why I **don't** understand why people keep **up**voting this.

If the dns-name doesn't exist, which is quite frankly the only case in which you want to do this in the first place, you can't set it, because .NET can't resolve it, and you can't override the .NET DNS resolver.

But what you can do, is setting a webproxy with the exact same IP as the destination server.

So, if your server IP is 28.14.88.71:

```
public class myweb : System.Net.WebClient
{
    protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(System.Uri address)
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest request = (System.Net.WebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        //string host = "redmine.nonexistantdomain.com";

        //request.Headers.GetType().InvokeMember("ChangeInternal",
        //    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        //    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
        //    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,
        //    request.Headers, new object[] { "Host", host }
        //);

        //server IP and port
        request.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("http://28.14.88.71:80");

        // .NET 4.0 only
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest foo = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)request;
        //foo.Host = host;

        // The below reflection-based operation is not necessary, 
        // if the server speaks HTTP 1.1 correctly
        // and the firewall doesn't interfere
        // https://yoursunny.com/t/2009/HttpWebRequest-IP/
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo horribleProxyServicePoint = (typeof(System.Net.ServicePoint))
            .GetField("m_ProxyServicePoint", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

        horribleProxyServicePoint.SetValue(foo.ServicePoint, false);
        return foo; // or return request; if you don't neet this
    }


    }
```

and voila, now

```
myweb wc = new myweb();
string str = wc.DownloadString("http://redmine.netexistantdomain.com");
```

and you get the correct page back, if 28.14.88.71 is a webserver with virtual name-based hosting (based on http-host-header).

Now you have the correct answer to the original question, for both WebRequest and WebClient. I think using custom sockets to do this would be the wrong approach, particularly when SSL should be used, and when an actual solution is that simple...