# Building an HTTPPing that can overide a Host File

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, http

I'm hoping to build an HTTPPing utility that can bypass our loadbalancer and test each front end in our SharePoint Environment.  Writing (or finding) an HTTPPing isn't difficult, it's getting it to operate in our environment.

We have five web applications in our SharePoint environment that run behind a load balancer that balances between 10 front ends.   Each of the five web applications are accessed via a DNS entry that maps to a virtual IP so:

```
webapp1.mycompany.com --> 10.20.30.10
webapp2.mycompany.com --> 10.20.30.11
webapp3.mycompany.com --> 10.20.30.12
webapp4.mycompany.com --> 10.20.30.13
webapp5.mycompany.com --> 10.20.30.14
```

The IP Addresses of the front end machine might be:

```
Front End 1  --> 10.22.33.40
Front End 2  --> 10.22.33.41
...
Front End 10 --> 10.22.33.49
```

Our SharePoint environment uses alternate access mappings, so I can't do http://10.22.33.40/, but have use http://webapp1.mycompany.com

I can access a machine directly if I change my host file to have the entry:

```
webapp1.mycompany.com --> 10.22.33.40
```

but 5 web applications x 10 front ends means 50 changes, and I figure there is a better way to do this.  I'd prefer that the program does not edit the host file.

Thanks, Tim

Comment: Why not temporarily add the AAMs for the IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

You could spoof the host header using reflection:

```
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(@"http://127.0.0.1/Test.html");

        wr.Headers.GetType().InvokeMember("ChangeInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, wr.Headers, new object[] { "Host", "www.example.com" });
        var resp = wr.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd().ToString());
```

Credit to [L.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7560279/573218) for his answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
public static bool Ping(string url, string actualTargetEnpoint)
{
    var uri = new UriBuilder(url);
    // take note of the original host to use for the "Host" header
    var originalHost = uri.Host;
    // swap out the actual endpoint we are going to be hitting
    uri.Host = actualTargetEnpoint;

    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri.ToString());
    // replace the host header on the request for the originally supplied target
    req.Host = originalHost;

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
}
```

.Net 4 allows you to manipulate the host directly. This means you can easily point your web request to a new endpoint whilst maintaining the original host header. No need for hosts file changes or special proxy configurations or the like. Just call like this:

```
var success = Ping("http://webapp1.mycompany.com/", "10.20.30.10");
```

We use something like this for exactly the purpose you are after.