# How to use reflection to change HttpWebRequest headers in Powershell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, reflection

I need to create an HttpWebRequest with specific headers using Powershell (v2) that are restricted by .NET. I read another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7560279) where this was done in C#, but I am running into difficulty accomplishing the same goal in Powershell

Here is what I have so far based off of the link above:

```
$httpWebRequest = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest][System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]$bflags = [Reflection.BindingFlags]"NonPublic" -bor [Reflection.BindingFlags]"Instance" -bor [Reflection.BindingFlags]"InvokeMethod"
$httpWebRequest.Headers.GetType().InvokeMember("ChangeInternal", $bflags, $null, $httpWebRequest.Headers, @{"Host" = "www.example.com"})
```

Unfortunately, the error response from Powershell is the following:

> Exception calling "InvokeMember" with "5" argument(s): "Method 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.ChangeInternal' not found."

How should I go about invoking "ChangeInternal"? Is the error I'm getting have anything to do with the wrong assembly version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final parameter of `InvokeMember` is an array of parameters and `ChangeInternal` takes two parameters, the name and the value. The error occurred because reflection could not find a method called `ChangedMember` accepting a single parameter. Use this:

```
$httpWebRequest.Headers.GetType().InvokeMember("ChangeInternal", $bflags, $null, $httpWebRequest.Headers, @("Host", "www.example.com"))
```

Comment: Oh, I get it. I naively assumed it was a hashtable. It does seem to be asking for System.Object[] args based on the definition. Thanks for the help!