# NetCore: How to send lower-case Keep-Alive header through HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, http, .net-core, request, keep-alive

I'm migrating one of my applications from .net 4.0 to .netcore and I'm facing some issues while trying to send a lower case keep-Alive header through HttpWebRequest.
In my previous code (the 4.0) I'm using the solution found here ([How to send lower-case Keep-Alive header through HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650236/how-to-send-lower-case-keep-alive-header-through-httpwebrequest)) and it works perfectly

```
request.Headers.GetType().InvokeMember(
"ChangeInternal",
BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
Type.DefaultBinder, 
request.Headers, 
new object[] { "Connection", "keep-alive" }
```

);

However, when trying to use the same function on .netcore I always receive an error "Method 'System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.ChangeInternal' not found."

Is there any other work around to use a lower case keep alive?

Comment: Try to check this solition https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612433/how-to-use-reflection-to-change-httpwebrequest-headers-in-powershell

Comment: I did, but still wasn't able to make it work.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If I simply add `request.Headers["Connection"] = "keep-alive";` it works just fine for me. Request header is lower case and also is the response header. (.NET Core 3.1)

Comment: This didn't use to work on .NetFramework (it generated an exception saying it is not possible to change this header), so I didn't even think to try that out.. Thanks!