# How to modify "Host" parameter in HttpWebRequest for C# Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, compact-framework

I am trying to change the value of "Host" parameters in the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7x3zz2.aspx) headers but I am getting error below:

**"This header must be modified with the appropriate property. at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.ThrowOnRestrictedHeader(String headerName)"**

I am trying to use the following code:

```
HttpWebRequest hbWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(WebService);
hbWebRequest.Method = "POST";
hbWebRequest.Headers["Host"] = WebURL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Found this link helpful
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ncl/archive/2009/07/20/new-ncl-features-in-net-4-0-beta-2.aspx

which gives the following solution

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/") as HttpWebRequest; 
request.Host = "contoso.com"; 
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Framework 4.0 you can use the [Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.host.aspx) property of the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7x3zz2.aspx) class.

```
hbWebRequest.Host = WebURL;
```

**Edit:** Possible duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450937/how-to-set-custom-host-header-in-httpwebrequest).

Comment: Hi David, Sorry to say but hbWebRequest.Host is not coming in Compact Framework.