# Check Load Balancing server using C#

Tags: c#, load-balancing

I have four application server for my application.Application is working on all server using load balancing.If one of my server goes down I have to check it manually using my system hosts file.To avoid this manual process I have created one program using C#.I write server IP address one by one in host file and remove previous one.

```
 private void RunWithUAC()
    {
        List<string> lstIPAddress = new List<string>();
        lstIPAddress.Add("1.1.1.1 example.com");
        lstIPAddress.Add("1.1.1.1 example.com");
        lstIPAddress.Add("1.1.1.1 example.com");
        lstIPAddress.Add("1.1.1.1 example.com");
        var systemPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System);
        Console.WriteLine(systemPath);
        var path = @"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts";

        foreach (var item in lstIPAddress)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty);
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText(path, item);

                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://example.com");
                request.Timeout = 10000;
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

But When second server goes down.It will give me timeout error for third server.
Please check the code and let me know what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1):

Probably some kind of connection pooling, HTTP pipelining or keep-alive. This is the wrong approach in the first place.

Connect directly to the right IP (`WebRequest.Create("https://1.1.1.1")`). If you need to send a `Host` header [add that manually to the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450937/how-to-set-custom-host-header-in-httpwebrequest).

Comment: I have a code but this margin is too small to fit it here. You might have to use a search engine.