# Change restricted HttpWebRequest headers in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, http-headers, httpwebrequest, host

I want to call a webpage by its IP address by adding custom values to request header for "host".
"
" Code:

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://1.1.1.1");
        request.Headers["Host"] = "xyz.net";
 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

But it gives an error:

> ArgumentException: restricted header

It seems that some headers cannot be modified in .net 2.0
so is there any way that I can change the host or change the .net version in unity to higher version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set custom "Host" header in HttpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450937/how-to-set-custom-host-header-in-httpwebrequest)

Comment: @joreldraw This is Unity. None of those should work since it uses reflection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot set some HTTP headers when using System.Net.WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239725/cannot-set-some-http-headers-when-using-system-net-webrequest)

Comment: ^ Explaination is in the answer to that question.  TL;DR, just set the `Host` property on the `HttpWebRequest` object itself instead of using the `Headers` property. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.host(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with reflection. Unfortunately, none of the C# answers from similar questions works because Unity is using Mono and their variable names are totally different making `GetField` unable to find the variable that's holding the headers.

Dump all the headers in the `HttpWebRequest` class with `HttpWebRequest.GetType().GetFields` then look for the name of the field that holds the headers. In my test, the field name is **`"webHeaders"`** and is a type of `WebHeaderCollection`.

Below is an extension method that modifies that **`"webHeaders"`**  from reflection:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void changeSysTemHeader(this HttpWebRequest request, string key, string value)
    {
        WebHeaderCollection wHeader = new WebHeaderCollection();
        wHeader[key] = value;


        FieldInfo fildInfo = request.GetType().GetField("webHeaders",
                                                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
                                                   | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
                                                   | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField);

        fildInfo.SetValue(request, wHeader);
    }

    public static void changeReflectionField(this HttpWebRequest request, string fieldName, object value)
    {
        FieldInfo fildInfo = request.GetType().GetField(fieldName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
                                                   | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
                                                   | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetField);

        fildInfo.SetValue(request, value);
    }
}
```

**USAGE**:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://1.1.1.1");

//Change Host header
request.changeSysTemHeader("Host", "xyz.net");

request.changeReflectionField("hostChanged", true);

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

This should work for any restricted header like **`User-Agent`**. Tested with **Unity 2017.2**. Mentioned the Unity version and how I found the field name so that when the variable name changes in the future, anyone can simply fix it.