# Set Custom Host Name as part of changing the Endpoint Address of a Soap Client

Tags: c#, soap, load-balancing, .net-4.5

I am presently in a scenario where I need to have multiple servers that live behind a Load Balancer talk to each other directly, and I need to communicate with specific servers for PUSH notifications. This is for a chat tool that requires users that have been moved to different servers by a load balancer to still be able to talk to one another live.

The actual pushes are being handled with Signal-R, and I have all of that working. So here is the actual complication:

Normally, this would be simple enough to do by targeting them via IP Address to bypass the load balancer. However, this is complicated because the servers expects a specific Host name or it will reject the request.

I know it is possible to do this with a [WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450937/how-to-set-custom-host-header-in-httpwebrequest), but would like to avoid having to build a proxy if I can help it.

Here is the piece I have where I'm trying to send a global push to tell everyone across all connected servers to update their buddy lists because someone logged in or out.

```
private void NotifyUsersChangedGlobal()
{
    List<string> addressesToNotify = ChatUsers.Select(x => x.ServerIP).Distinct().ToList();

    foreach (string address in addressesToNotify)
    {
        ChatUplinkSoapClient client = BuildClient(address);
        client.NotifyUsersChanged();
    }
}
```

And this is the Client Builder where (I assume) I need to handle assigning the custom Host name to ride on top of the IP Address

```
private ChatUplinkSoapClient BuildClient(string endpointIP)
{
    string relativeUrl = "/WebServices/ChatUplink.asmx";

    //Turn on HTTPS
    HttpBindingBase binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);

    //Link together the IP Address and the asmx route
    EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(endpointIP + relativeUrl);

    //Make the Client
    ChatUplinkSoapClient client = new ChatUplinkSoapClient(binding, endpoint);

    //Need to set Host header to "HostHeaderName", or the server will reject the request.


    return client;
}
```

Ideas?