# HttpWebRequest to a SSL web site on a server specified by IP address (WebProxy)

Tags: c#, https, http-headers

Following the idea about using a WebProxy to make an http request to a server by IP address as demonstrated in the following answers :

[Request Web Page in c# spoofing the Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359041/request-web-page-in-c-spoofing-the-host)

[Http Request - Bypass DNS [.Net]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323264/http-request-bypass-dns-net)

I'm trying to achive the same goal with an HTTPS request. I would like to still use an HttpWebRequest object in order to let the system automatically manage the certificate validation.

Unfortunately, this is not working and I get a System.Net.WebException with WebExceptionStatus.Timeout status.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
    "https://www.mywebiste.net/"
    );
System.Net.WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(
    "192.168.3.14"
    , 443   // HTTPS
    );
request.Proxy = proxy;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()
```

Any Help appreciated.
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting BYPassOnLocal as false.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234s6ee9.aspx